# Search Json with null field value sql

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Using SQL statement to query JSON field value that return `"null"` (String null) instead of `NULL` value

Sample JSON value in field name `field`

```
{
  "a" : "a",
  "b" : null
}
```

Query statement

```
SELECT field->>'$.b' FROM table_a;
```

Results

```
+---------------+-----------------------+
| field->>'$.b' | ISNULL(field->>'$.b') |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| null          |                     0 |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Is anyone have way to handle `"null"` (String null)?

Comment: Try Standard SQL `NULLIF(field->>'$.b', 'null')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, to handle the case when `null` values is present.

```
SELECT IFNULL(field->>'$.b', 'null') FROM table_a;
```